# Performing a union in linq using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I cannot seem to figure out how to do a full outer join in Linq using lambda expressions. Here is a stripped down sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
void Main()
{
var myPets = new List<petInfo>();
var yourpets = new List<petInfo>();

myPets.Add(new petInfo("me", "dog","Rex"));
myPets.Add(new petInfo("me", "fish","Goldy"));
myPets.Add(new petInfo("me", "iguana","Spikey"));

yourpets.Add(new petInfo("you", "dog","Spot"));
yourpets.Add(new petInfo("you", "cat","Tigger"));
yourpets.Add(new petInfo("you", "bird","Polly"));

var ourPets = myPets.GroupJoin(yourpets, mine => mine.PetType, yours => yours.PetType, (mine, yours) => new { WHAT GOES HERE???});
}
```

where petInfo is a boring class:

```
public class petInfo
{
public string Owner;
public string PetType;
public string PetName;

public petInfo(string owner, string petType, string petName)
{
    Owner = owner;
    PetType = petType;
    PetName = petName;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting ourPets to have the following records after the outer join:

```
PetType MyOwnerName MyPetName YourOwnerName YourPetName
bird                          you           Polly
cat                           you           Tigger
dog     me          Rex       you           Spot
fish    me          Goldy
iguana  me          Spikey
```

I've figured out almost everything else with linq and lambda, but for some reason joins are causing me all sorts of grief. I usually wind up just looping over the two sets and creating a third manually, but I've decided I want to solve this once and for all. All of the examples I found here seem to be a bit off or have requirements specific to this problem. I haven't found a good basic lambda outer join yet.

*edit* I have looked at the referenced solution and would like to implement this without using an extension method if possible. If it isn't possible, then I'll do so, but I love linq and lambda's because the code is so clean and it just feels like this should be able to be accomplished in a much simpler manner.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/fe39ecbeb2a72c471821e83d5c845649

Comment: @Hogan - thanks for the link, but it is returning separeate results on Dog for "me" and "you" where I am trying to have one row where both sets have the same pet.

Comment: @usr / fubo - I was looking at it as a SQL outer join. I'll also edit the equest as I'd like to do so without extension methods if possible form the linked solution.

Comment: in that case you have to use one of the methods in the linked examples